# Can we call ASPX (webforms) from ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, openid-connect

Looking forward to work on OPENID connect project with JAWT (JSON Web Token). As its legacy app written in ASP.Net 3.5 Web Forms. Planning to add Gate wrapper of ASP.Net Core ( Core will handle OPENID interaction and call web forms after creating required sessions). Can anyone help me with some pointers how I can achieve it ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the only way to use aspx with .net core is if all connections are made by API. 
Razor pages is the new aspx option.

Comment: What do you mean by "call ASPX"?

Comment: I mean , web forms application in ASP.Net (3.5 framework)